# Comparing String and Enumeration

Tags: scala

I have an enumeration in scala mapped to strings in JPA. For more comfortable coding, I defined implicit conversions between them. So I now can define value `val person.role = "User"`, - `person.role` is the enumeration type `"User"` a String so there's the conversion. But when I try to compare these two, I always get false, because the `def equals (arg0: Any) : Boolean` takes `Any` so there's not any conversion triggered. I need some explicit conversion, but my plan was to be able to omit that, what do you think is the best practice | neatest solution here?

Comment: Are you basing this mapping on 'Enumeration' and 'Value'?

Comment: @Thomas yes I'm using scala's `scala.Enumeration` and `scala.Enumeration.Value`

Comment: What's the context / use case for the comparison?  Pattern matching may provide a better solution, but it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Value("User")` in your `Enumeration` is of type `Val`. And I believe it's implementation of `equals` does not compare the string name of the value. I think one heavy handed way of doing this is creating your own `Enumeration` and `Val` so that it returns true if the name match.

But in my code uses, not with JPA, I always convert the string into the `MyEnumeration.Value`.  This is easy with things like:

```
 object E extends Enumeration { val User = Value("User") }

 scala> val a = E.withName("User")
 a: E.Value = User
```

Note that when using `withName`, if the  string does not match any name in the enumeration you get an exception.

Then always use the enumeration fields in your comparisons:

```
scala> a == E.User
res9: Boolean = true
```

If JPA only returns a string, and there is no way around it. Then I think the best option is to either convert the value to string and match string to string, or upgrade the string  to a Val and compare Val. Mixing these types will not work for comparison, unless you you implement some kind of extension to the `equals` method, and that is tricky.

Answer (score 16):

Expanding on Thomas's answer, if you're using the comparison to branch, using pattern matching may be more appropriate:

```
object Role extends Enumeration {
   val User = MyValue("User")
   val Admin = MyValue("Admin")

   def MyValue(name: String): Value with Matching = 
         new Val(nextId, name) with Matching

   // enables matching against all Role.Values
   def unapply(s: String): Option[Value] = 
      values.find(s == _.toString)

   trait Matching {
      // enables matching against a particular Role.Value
      def unapply(s: String): Boolean = 
            (s == toString)
   }
}
```

You can then use this as follows:

```
def allowAccess(role: String): Boolean = role match {
   case Role.Admin() => true
   case Role.User() => false
   case _ => throw ...
}
```

or

```
// str is a String
str match { 
   case Role(role) => // role is a Role.Value
   case Realm(realm) => // realm is a Realm.Value
   ...
}
```